# Creating nested json with list from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I have a DataFrame with these columns: `id, jan_x, jan_y, feb_x, feb_y, ..., dec_x, dec_y` that I would like export as a json that is structured like this:

```
{
    "id1": [
        [jan_x, feb_x, ..., dec_x],
        [jan_y, feb_y, ..., dec_y]
    ],
    "id2": [
        [jan_x, feb_x, ..., dec_x],
        [jan_y, feb_y, ..., dec_y]
    ]
}
```

The initial keys e.g., `id1` correspond to an id in column `id` of my dataframe. Without any custom parsing function is there a straight forward functional way of achieving this? I have tried dumping it as a json but the desired list structure isn't captured.

Here is a sample data frame with just two months.

```
data = {'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'jan_x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'jan_y': [5, 6, 7, 8],
        'feb_x': [9, 10, 11 12],
        'feb_y': [13 14, 15, 16]}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Sample Output:

```
{
    "1": [
        [1, 9],
        [5, 13]
    ],
    "2": [
        [2, 10],
        [6, 14]
    ],
    "3": [
        [3, 11],
        [7, 15]
    ],
    "4": [
        [4, 12],
        [8, 16]
    ]
}
```

Comment: import json and then saving your data as data: with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)?

Comment: @Elkhan I tried this but it doesn't capture the nested part

Comment: Can you provide the input dataframe please?

Comment: @Corralien Good point. Added a sample dataframe with two months but assume the solution should extend to more than that

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

Use `to_dict('list')` after aggregate by common suffix ('x', 'y', ...):

```
import json

out = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
         .set_index('id').groupby(level=0, axis=1, sort=False)
         .agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).T.to_dict('list'))
jd = json.dumps(out, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
{'1': [[1, 9], [5, 13]],
 '2': [[2, 10], [6, 14]],
 '3': [[3, 11], [7, 15]],
 '4': [[4, 12], [8, 16]]}
```

Comment: Sorry I think I wasn't as clear as I could've been. I updated the question with a sample output. Your output is close but not quite there.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff. I fixed again my answer (sorry). Now I got the expected output. Use `jd` instead of `out` to get the json output.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "any custom parsing function", but here is my attempt.

The solution uses `iterrows` go iterate through rows. For each row, I take the columns that ends with _x using `x_columns` variable that I defined above, and the same for columns that ends with _y. `row[x_columns]` gives you the values as a pandas Series, therefore you need to convert it to a list before adding to fit your desired format. I append all those to a result variable and print the result variable at the end.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe for demo
data={"id":[15,12,13,22,32,11], "jan_x":[15,12,13,22,32,11],"jan_y":[12,21,23,22,56,11], "feb_x":[15,12,13,22,32,11],"feb_y":[12,21,23,22,56,11]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

# Get columns that ends with _x and _y
x_columns = [col for col in df if col.endswith('_x')]
y_columns = [col for col in df if col.endswith('_y')]

# Iterate through rows
results = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  results.append({
    "id"+str(row['id']): [
        list(row[x_columns]),
        list(row[y_columns])
        ]
    })
    
print(result)
```

Here is my example input:

```
   id  jan_x  jan_y  feb_x  feb_y
0  15     15     12     15     12
1  12     12     21     12     21
2  13     13     23     13     23
3  22     22     22     22     22
4  32     32     56     32     56
5  11     11     11     11     11
```

and here is the output:

```
[{'id15': [[15, 15], [12, 12]]}, 
 {'id12': [[12, 12], [21, 21]]}, 
 {'id13': [[13, 13], [23, 23]]}, 
 {'id22': [[22, 22], [22, 22]]}, 
 {'id32': [[32, 32], [56, 56]]}, 
 {'id11': [[11, 11], [11, 11]]}
 ]
```

Comment: Good solution. It works. Trying to optimize this now. Thanks